# Trying to create JSON file with name of XML file and load data from xml file by using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Trying to create JSON file same name as XML file and dump XML data into that using Python

```
import os
import json
import xmltodict

# Reading file from directory
with os.scandir('C:/jsonfile/') as entries:
    for entry in entries:
        name=(entry.name)  
        print(name)
        base = os.path.splitext(name)[0] #Getting name of the file
        f= open("C:/jjsonfile/"+base+".json","w+")
        with open("C:/jsonfile/"+name, 'r') as f: #Creating JSON file
            xmlString = f.read()
        jsonString = json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(xmlString), indent=4) 
        with open(f, 'w') as f: #Loading data into JSON file.
            f.write(jsonString)
```

> 1019586313.xml
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>        13             xmlString = f.read()
>        14         jsonString = json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(xmlString), indent=4)
>   ---> 15         with open(f, 'w') as f:
>        16             f.write(jsonString)
>        17
>
> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not
>   _io.TextIOWrapper

Comment: try doing json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(str(xmlString)), indent=4)

Comment: Nope..!! Main issue with "not _io.TextIOWrapper"

Answer (score 0):

When using `open` to create the json file you need to pass it the path to the file you want to create,what you are doing is that you are passing it the object f,

```
with open(f, 'w') as f:
```

which is a `_io.TextIOWrapper` object that you created with

```
with open("C:/jsonfile/"+name, 'r') as f
```

so in order to fix this, you need to pass it the name of the json file you wa to create, so you should do this

```
with open("C:/jjsonfile/"+base+".json","w+") as f:
```

instead of this

```
with open(f, 'w') as f:
```

and remove this line

```
f= open("C:/jjsonfile/"+base+".json","w+")
```

Comment: Nope. No luck..!!

Comment: still the same error?, what did you change exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import json
import xmltodict


with os.scandir('C:/ARP_project/') as entries:
    for entry in entries:
        name=(entry.name)
        print(name)
        base = os.path.splitext(name)[0]
        jsname= "C:/ARP_Json/"+ base+".json" # created Variable for json file name
        f= open(jsname,"w+")
        with open("C:/ARP_project/"+name, 'r') as f:
            xmlString = f.read()
        jsonString = json.dumps(xmltodict.parse(xmlString), indent=4) 
        with open(jsname, 'w') as f:
            f.write(jsonString)
```